# Resize letter by letter a word but keeping the padding between the letters

Tags: css, css-animations

I want to make an in and out animation to show a username letter by letter. Each letter is resized after another. The anchor of the whole word should be in the middle, but each letter should be where it will be once the whole word has appeared.

Here is where I am at the moment:

***HTML***

```
<div id="username">
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0s, 3s">U</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.1s, 3.1s">S</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.2s, 3.2s">E</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.3s, 3.3s">R</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.4s, 3.4s">N</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.5s, 3.5s">A</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.6s, 3.6s">M</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.7s, 3.7s">E</span>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
#username {
  text-align: center;
}

.animate-username-letter {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 50px;
  animation: forwards;
  animation-name: animate-username-in, animate-username-out;
  animation-delay: 2s, 6s;
  animation-duration: 0.10s;
}

@keyframes animate-username-in {
  from {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
  to {
      font-size: 50px;
  }
}

@keyframes animate-username-out {
  from {
      font-size: 50px;
  }
  to {
    font-size: 0px;
  }
}
```

***JSFIDDLE***

https://jsfiddle.net/zc5u1tmk/2/

Because the word is centered, and because all the letters are placed between each other, we can see a movement of the letters from the center to the left and the opposite when the word disappear. How to make sure that it doesn't happend? I tried to use a fixed width, but it's not possible as some letters are wider than some others and it will overlap or create gaps between letters.

In red, the word before it disappear and in black the animation played. This is what I could achieved and what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

Comment: Do you consider a monospace font?

Comment: I thought about it but no

Comment: Maybe the solution is to wrap each letter with the same letter with transparency and no animations, then overlap the parent with the child ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate `scale` instead of `font-size`

```css
#username {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.animate-username-letter {
  font-family: Tahoma;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 50px;
  animation: forwards;
  animation-name: animate-username-in, animate-username-out;
  animation-delay: 2s, 6s;
  animation-duration: 0.50s;
  text-align: center;
  transform: scale(0);
  transform-origin: bottom;
}

@keyframes animate-username-in {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes animate-username-out {
  from {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="username">
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0s, 3s">U</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.1s, 3.1s">S</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.2s, 3.2s">E</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.3s, 3.3s">R</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.4s, 3.4s">N</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.5s, 3.5s">A</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.6s, 3.6s">M</span>
  <span class="animate-username-letter" style="animation-delay:0.7s, 3.7s">E</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Using a fixed width would result in gaps or overlaps as I'm not using a monospace font

Comment: Udpated the code and animated the scale of the fonts and set the font-size instead

Comment: Amazing ! You even added the transform-origin bottom I needed. Thank you very much !